# Get name model in vue js with help id input or name

Tags: vue.js

Can i get model name if i now id input?
For examle

```
<input v-model="data.name" id="name_db">
```

I have in db value for data.name

Before vue i did this:

```
   valuesFromDb.forEach(data=>{
  if(data.fromdb==name_db)
      $("#name_db").val(data.fromdb)
  }
    ...
```

But it can't work with vueJS

I know i can do this:

data.name = data.fromdb

But i have many data in db and before vue i put data with help forloop.

Model and id have different names ​​and it will take a long time to manually iterate through all the data

Now i want get model name and put value to it

Somethinks like this:

```
   var modelName =  $("#name_db").getModelNameVue();
  modelName=data.fromdb
```

If i do this, in input value change but in data dont

```
 data(){
return{
 mainPdf:{
  left: 5,
  bottom:5,
  top:5,
  right:5

    }
}
}
 <input v-model="mainPdf.left" id="left_margin">
 <input v-model="mainPdf.bottom" id="bot_margin">
 <input v-model="mainPdf.isMargin" id="right_margin">
<input v-model="mainPdf.isMargin" id="up_margin">

  getFromdb(){
     api.getFromdb(e=>{ // string=e 
        var string =   "left_margin=0&bot_margin=1&right_margin=2&up_margin=3"
          var rPlus = /\+/g;
            $.each( string.split( "&" ), function( index, field ) {
                 $.each( string.split( "&" ), function( index, field ) {
                     var current = field.split( "=" );
                     if( current[ 1 ] &&  current[ 0 ]) {
                                var name = decodeURIComponent(current[0].replace(rPlus, "%20"));
                                var value = decodeURIComponent(current[1].replace(rPlus, "%20"));
                                  $("#"+ name).val(value);

                            }
                        });


                    })

                })
```

I can't dynamic-binding because i can't change name of properties in mainPdf, because i have entity with same fields(left,bottom,top,right) in my backend

==========**i found solution**

i used dispatchEvent

```
$("#" + NAME).prop("checked", true);
$("#"+ NAME")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); //or input
```

Comment: jQuery is rarey ever necessary when using Vue.js.  The fact that you are setting anything to v-model means you automatically have access to it, as it should be a piece of [data](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data) you are assigning to... With proper setup, you can dynamically set v-model to an array to handle practically unlimited amount of elements.  Include more code snippets showing your HTML template and the format of your db data and I and/or others can help show how to dynamically bind an array to hold the values of your multiple HTML elements.

Comment: @yoduh okay i did

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue.js and dynamic programming techniques, it's a piece of cake.

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-binding', {
  template: `
   <div style="display: flex;">
    <input
      v-for="field in Object.keys(mainPdf)" :key="field"
      v-model="mainPdf[field]"
    >
   </div>
  `,

  data() {
    return {
      mainPdf: {},
    };
  },

  methods: {
    fromDb(val = 'left_margin=0&bot_margin=1&right_margin=2&up_margin=3') {
      const db = new URLSearchParams(val);
      this.mainPdf = Object.fromEntries(db);
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fromDb();
  },
});

new Vue({ el: '#app' });
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <dynamic-binding></dynamic-binding>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't dynamic-binding because i can't change name of properties in mainPdf

Comment: There is no limitation in mutating `mainPdf`. Run/manipulate the snippet code, then let me know if your issue persists.

Comment: i have entity in server with this fields:
mainPdf:{
  left: 5,
  bottom:5,
  top:5,
  right:5

    }
Because of it i cant cnahge properties in painpdf

Comment: I cannot get your point! Sorry! Anyway, I cover the whole idea of manipulating dynamic values, and how to parse and render them. You can change `mainPdf` var name to anything else. Call me or join me in a public chat to investigate more.